# how to apply different styles to views for round & square watches inside BoxInsetLayout?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, boxinsetlayout

I am using LinearLayout inside **BoxInsetLayout** and required to have **gravity center** for **round** face & **left** for **square** face.

It's possible with WatchViewStub but i have to use BoxInsetLayout.

so is there way we can apply 2 different styles for each faces?

Comment: Perhaps you are better off making 2 layouts in qualified directories (e.g. `layout-round` or `layout-notround`). The common content can be `<include>`ed in both.

Comment: @Karakuri this both layout added in API 23. is there a way to do for lower version?

Comment: You might want to check the documentation about [Creating Watch Faces](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/index.html), it stated Android 4.3 (API level 18) or higher on the handheld device and Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher on the wearable device. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot those 2 directories is only working with API 23 or greater.. so is there any way so we can apply 2 different styles for round & rect view inside boxinsetLayout?

Answer (score 0):

You can check at runtime if the screen is round using the following:

```
private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {
    boolean mIsRound;

    @Override
    public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
        mIsRound = insets.isRound();
    }
    ...
}
```

This is described in the [Creating Watch Faces](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/issues.html#ScreenShape) developer guide. [`WindowInsets.isRound()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets.html#isRound()) was added in API 20, so this should be available to you. Based on this value you can set the appropriate gravity for your content.

Comment: yeah it's way.. but i think it will increase more time complexity if we have more views. so it would be better if google provides such solution in support library.

Comment: i have added feature request https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232122&thanks=232122&ts=1484288818 . can you please take follow up as you are working at google :)

Comment: @SanketKachhela There's really no way to backport configuration qualifiers for resources, so I doubt there would be anything added to the support library.